# Sphere shaders disappear when inside in the game object Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have this sphere with a transperent material and when I go inside of it, it's like the sphere is invincible [image]
[image]

How can I fix that? So, I want when the camera is inside the sphere, to see at least the outline. I did do my research and the solution I found is to make my own shader, but I am still a newbie in Unity, so I was wondering if there is another way, or an easy one to make the shader.

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses backface culling, which is where faces only have one side (see [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/backface-culling-in-unity.48919/) post), so you will have to modify the mesh so that the faces point both outside and inside (duplicating it and inverting the normals will work).